# Does ImmutableMap.Builder have a limit?

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public enum Animal {
   BEAR,
   SHEEP,
   LION;

   private static final Map<String, Animal> MAPPING = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Animal>()
      .put("BLACK_BEAR", BEAR)
      .put("WHITE_BEAR", BEAR)
      ...
      .put("African Lion", LION)
      .build()
}
```

About 1500 map entries.

I try to build my application and I get the following error:

```
    [javac] An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.StackOverflowError
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:200)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:67)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:386)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:284)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:374)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:340)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:200)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:67)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:386)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:284)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:374)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:340)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:200)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:67)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:386)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:284)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:374)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:340)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:200)
    [javac]     at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:67)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:386)
    [javac]     at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:284)
```

I tried reducing the size of the map to 15ish and it builds fine. Is there a limit to the size we can harcode a static immutable map? I didn't see any limitation in the documentation. What could the issue be?

Comment: This is failing in lombok code.  But your example doesn't use project lombok.  It would be helpful if you provided a more complete (even if truncated) example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MarkPeters I wonder if it's simply a problem with implicit size constraints on Lombok's internal data structures.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the later lines of the stack trace, before it starts repeating

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: Without investigating into lombok, based on the class names (AST, javac) I would definitely think that's a possibility--that compiler limits are being blown.

Comment: @MarkPeters This is basically exactly what I have. There's nothing else to show. As mentioned by chrylis this might actually be something else which uses Lombok internally but kinda surprised that this doesn't work..

Comment: As a note, is there a specific reason why those items aren't constructor parameters on the enum instances?

Comment: This is just a quick hack I need to put together. Basically, we can have different types of animals (white bear, black bear) and I would like to categorize them to a high level enum (there are about only 10 enum values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ImmutableBuilder; it's the fact that your source file is now such a gigantic pile of AST nodes that lombok's processing ends up taking too much memory, which, I guess, given that javac can handle it, is technically a bug in lombok. In other words, the compiler can't manage to turn your java file into a class file, but if it could, it would work fine*.

I would in general consider any source file that tries to define that much data in source as a code smell.

I suggest you take whatever data this is and put it in a text file.

Put this text file together with your source files; if you use maven / the more or less standard source dir structure, you'd have, say:

```
src/main/java/com/foo/yourpkg/Animal.java
src/main/resources/com/foo/yourpkg/AnimalData.txt
```

which will automatically result in the txt file being in the same place as your class file is, even in jars. Then, to read it, from within your animal file:

```
public enum Animal {

    private static final Map<String, Animal> MAPPING;
    static {
        try {
            Map<String, String> example = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try (var in = Animal.class.getResourceAsStream("AnimalData.txt")) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                    String[] p = line.split("\t", 2);
                    map.put(p[0], p[1]);
                }
            }
            MAPPING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalError("data corrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

This hypothetical example would require you to put tab-separated string pairs in the text file. You can use this example and adjust it to your needs.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a core contributor of lombok, but this is about as low a priority as I can imagine, and we have plenty of bug reports to dig through before we'd get to 'out of memory issues if you try to do a 1500-size immutablemap builder in source'.

*) Possibly; class files have limits too, it's possible if you remove lombok or add memory, that the compiler will in a later phase still end up refusing to compile this code because it would blow past the 64k bytecode limit on your initialization.

Comment: Interesting. So, this will fail even if I don't use ImmutableMap builder? This is failing because I am storing a gigantic map in a static variable?

Comment: Does it fail at the moment if you *do* have the enormous `enum`, but *don't* create the Map?

Comment: Three bytes to push the string constant, three bytes for the `invokevirtual`. He'd have to get to 9000+ entries before hitting the 64k limit.

Comment: @no_clue_so no, it is failing because your .java file is so large, the compilation process falls down trying to work its way through it all.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Wouldn't this cause an issue to the service? If for some reason there is.a transient read issue, then what?

Comment: 'transient read' is a database thing, this is files. Your code is in class files. keyword: __files__. That txt file is as reliable as your code is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @rzwitserloot above, but there are some things you could try:

1. Just increase your stack size by adding `-Xss4m` (or higher) to the jvm that's running your build.
2. *edit* As the enum itself is small, you could do this:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum Animal {
    BEAR("white bear", "black bear", "brown bear"),
    DOG("mongrel", "cross"),
    CAT("blah3");

    private final String[] blah1;

    private static final Map<String, Animal> MAPPING = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (Animal animal: Animal.values()) {
            for (String tag : animal.blah1) {
                MAPPING.put(tag, animal);
            }
        }
    }

    Animal(String... blah1) {
        this.blah1 = blah1;
    }


    public static void main(String... s) {
        String animal = "black bear";
        System.out.println(" A " + animal + " is a " + MAPPING.get(animal));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have created enum values, but I actually wanted to convert "white bear" -> Animal.Bear, "black bear" -> Animal.Bear etc. Basically various animal types to high level Animal enums. I only have about 10 enum values.

Comment: I've updated the answer to accomodate what I think you are trying to do

Comment: that is an interesting solution! How many values can an enum take? For example, how many Animal.BEAR("value1, ... "valuN") can I define? What if one of the enum values has 1000 values. Would it work?

Comment: I just tested it with 1000 types of bear and it was fine. That's without Lombok of course -- you haven't said what your Lombok configuration is.